# Coordinate system in GDAL

Tags: c++, gis, gdal, coordinate-systems

I'm developing a software which takes an SXF file as input, and does some calculations on C++ using [GDAL](https://gdal.org/). The problem is, I'm not sure which coordinate system is used by SXF.

When I try to output coordinates of LineStrings and Points, it shows lat-lon coordinates, but calculations seem to be wrong, it seems that GDAL parses coordinates as rectangular XYZ, not LatLon.
What I need as a result, is to create custom Line with my own custom coordinates and calculate distances to MultiLineStrings from input file.
Is there an option to detect or manually set the coordinate system for input file, or do conversion in runtime?

```
CPLSetConfigOption( "SXF_SET_VERTCS", "ON");
GDALAllRegister();

poDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx( "/path/to/map.sxf", GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL );

if( poDS == NULL ) {
    qDebug() << "Load failed";
} else {
    qDebug() << "Dataset successfully opened";
}

OGRLineString line1;

line1.set3D(true);
line1.set3D(true);
line1.setPoint(0, new OGRPoint(69.2144, 51.6312, 0));
line1.setPoint(1, new OGRPoint(68.8467, 49.0076, 0));

OGRLayer *poLayer = poDS->GetLayerByName("Relief");
OGRGeometry *poGeometry;

for( auto& poFeature: poLayer )
{
    poGeometry = poFeature->GetGeometryRef();

    if( poGeometry != NULL)
    {
        OGRMultiLineString *string = poGeometry->toMultiLineString();
        int dist = line1.Distance(string) / 1000;
        qDebug() << "Distance" << dist;
        if (line1.Intersects(string)) {
            qDebug() << "Has intersection with line string";
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`OGR` methods in GDAL are based on GEOS and perform geometry calculations on an Euclidean plane. The coordinates you set have no longitude or latitude meaning for OGR, they are just Cartesian coordinates.

GDAL itself does not include geodetic distance calculations. However PROJ - one of underlying libraries includes GeographicLib - which is the base library you need in this case.

Refer to this question for what you need to do: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/using-gdal-c-to-calculate-distance-in-meters